# Start fragment only when tab is selected

Tags: android

I have a view pager with 2 tabs, the thing is, as soon as I open the Activity, both the tabs(i.e fragments) start(try to load data). Is there a way I can start the fragment only when the tab is selected.

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter((MFragmentActivity ) this,
                mViewPager);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB-1"),
TabOneFragment.class, null);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB-2"),
TabTwoFragment.class, null);

public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
            ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public PagerAdapter(MFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return (SherlockFragment) Fragment.instantiate(mContext,
                info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Comment: set the viewpager offset limit to 1

Comment: @KapilVats AFAIK..It loads two pages..right ?

Comment: That's a complete different condition which is related to keeping the tab data in memory. I mean If I set it to 1 every time I change the tabs, the page starts loading from 1st.