# How to load the fragment activity oncreate() method of the actionbar selected tab only if the tab is selected?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I am using viewpager and actionbar tabs (4 tabs). When the Main activity starts, it loads the 4 fragments data.

how to make it load only the selected tab data?

Also when I select tab 1, tab1 and tab0 loads.

If I swipe between tab0 and tab1 , onstart() for both tabs not called.

If I select tab2 and then select tab0, onstart() for tab0 loads.

If I swipe between tab2 and tab3  , onstart() for both tabs not called.

MainActivity.java

```
MainPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;
ActionBar actionBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabsPagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.doros)).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.esteshara)).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aswak)).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.akhbar)).setTabListener(this));


    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);



}

 @Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
```

MainPageAdapter.java

```
 public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.IconTabProvider{

public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ar,
        R.drawable.ar,
        R.drawable.ar,
        R.drawable.ar
};



@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
   switch (position)
   {
       case 3: return new NewsFragment();
       case 1: return new ConsultationFragment();
       case 2: return new IndecesFragment();
       case 0: return new LessonsFragment();
       default: return null;
   }
}



@Override
public int getPageIconResId(int i) {
    return tabIcons[i];
}
```

}

I found this link, but its not helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944138/start-fragment-only-when-tab-is-selected)

Comment: That,s how the pagerAdapter works, you have to right your own logic to prevent this, like take boolean value for four fragments, and enable them when tab is selected. And load fragments based on TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that when I select a tab , its fragment activity onresume() or oncreate is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I have created a static variable to store selected tab index.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    sharedVariables.setSelectedTab(tab.getPosition());
```

Since Viewpager loads the selected page and the left page and the right page if they exist every time the page changed, so I override this function to check if this fragment is the one visible to user and then call onresume method.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
            onResume();
    } else {
        // Do your Work
    }
}
```

Comment: to add to this i will say do not call onResume() directly what ever you have in your onresume put in a method and call that rather,and also call that method in your onresume so it works normal

Comment: Please, do not call onResume(), it's a method that is already called by Android and it should be reserved to the system. You risk to have your Fragment in a inconsistent state if you call those methods.

Answer (score 1):

With ViewPager I always extend Fragment [setMenuVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setMenuVisibility(boolean)). It is called with *true* when the Fragment is visible, and with *false* when it's not. When it's visible, you can perform all the actions you need.