# Fragment lifecycle Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-lifecycle

As answered below. The best approach is to add a listener to the viewpager to know when each fragment is selected.

This way the activity can trigger fragment refresh listener through an interface for example.

Comment: its viewPager okay, research on how viewpager works and some things will come to light for you, but if they load on startup then they are in memory and switch through does not call any lifecycle

Comment: thank you, I will look better into it, is there any way I can force the onCreate again? or this isn't a good practice?

Comment: no android handles initialisation of your Fragments so you can not directly onCreate() to get the effect you want, i wouldn't do it though,

Answer (score 1):

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222735/how-to-load-the-fragment-activity-oncreate-method-of-the-actionbar-selected-ta) both answers and comment it is what you need. to also think of a clearer solution, the codes you want to call when you flip them put them in a `public method` in your `Fragment` class, then in your onPageSelected in your ViewPager the particular Fragment that is being accessed either by position (or anyway you want to do it like `ViewPager.getItem(pos)`) which will return a Fragment and you can check if that Fragment is an instanceof your preferred Fragment class and cast it to it and call your code

```
//suppose i have my fragment via myViewp.getItem(2)
if(fragmentObject instanceof MyFragmentClass){
    //do work
 }
 //put else and check for others
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no immediate callback into the Fragment; from the framework, all three of the Fragment's lifecycles are identical: they are attached to the activity, created, create a view and resumed. None of those callbacks relate to how they appear within the ViewPager, and for good reason.

You are instead interested in the callbacks within the ViewPager. For this, you can register a [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html):

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // If you would like to have more granular control than onPageSelected(),
    // you may inspect when the user "begins to scroll" to the next page
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = mAdapter.getItem(position);
    if (fragment instanceof OnMyFragmentSelectedListener) {
        ((OnMyFragmentSelectedListener) fragment).onMyFragmentSelected();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
}
```

In the snippet above, I've introduced an interface called OnMyFragmentSelectedListener. If you have your fragments implement it, and implement the `onMyFragmentSelected()` method, the ViewPager will inform your fragment when its page has been selected.

You can do some fun things by using the OnPageChangeListener, for instance animating between fragments as in the [JazzyViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager). In your case, you can instead begin loading your additional data when the listener is called.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the data you want by setArguments.

```
 ChildFragment fragment = new ChildFragment();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putInt("PARAMETER", param);
 fragment .setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: While this is true, I don't believe this answer addresses the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link. It is sharing data between two fragments using new android architecture and dagger 2. 
https://github.com/MohitGoel9456/Android-Live-Data-Dagger2
No need to share data using arguments and bundle as it is old way.